# How do you add a timestamp URI to an image_tag in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, random, uri

Just like the title says :

```
 = image_tag @organization.logo.url(:cropped)
```

I want this to appear as

```
<img src="picture.jpg?23412341234" />
```

Comment: I am having the same issue but only on assets obtained through carrierwave/gridfs(mongodb). I wonder if your issue is similar. If I were to do: `= image_tag 'picture.jpg'` It would come out: `<img src="picture.jpg?23412341234" />` But not if I generate the picture through carrierwave.

Comment: Interesting. No I'm not using carrierwave. But curious nonetheless if there's a mutual bug here. Let me know if you find a way to bypass this.

Comment: i'm having the same problem with carrierwave images

Answer (score 1):

Isn't this already the default in Rails?

That's called an asset timestamp and should reflect the latest time that the asset was modified.

Comment: I'm reading the documentation and that seems true, but its never been turned on for any of my apps I've ever built. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have something as follows in your configuration files (environment.rb, development.rb ...). This line of code disables asset timestamps.

```
ENV['RAILS_ASSET_ID'] = ''
```

Comment: Hmm nothing in my config files that say this.